# Is there an alternative to Code Contracts for declaring coding assumptions?

Tags: c#, code-contracts

I use Code Contracts. I like Code Contracts. [Code Contracts](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/contracts/) for C#, however, are far from perfect. Most of the issues related to them I have been able to maneuver around or soften with policies. Still... there are a few parts of it that make me cringe (for example, having to implement ContractClasses for abstractions).

The only real alternatives I found were an open source library that isn't any better than CC, and using regular guards (which may violate [LSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)).

Is there another better option that I have missed? I ask not out of desperation, but just for the sake of knowing all my options.

Comment: This isn't a practical answer for your question right now, but you might find it interesting that there is a [discussion on Roslyn](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/119) about the possibility of language-level contracts in a future version of C#.

Comment: That's what I thought, but hearing it from the community is a sanity check for myself and potentially useful information for others. I would accept that as an answer if it were posted as such. Also: yes Roslyn please. :)

Comment: The only (spontaneous!) idea I come up with is: write your own! Using AOP, something like MethodDecorators.Fody or postsharps method interception... I have not thought this through and I'm pretty sure it won't work for certain use- cases. May also be quite of an overhead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not aware of any alternative options that you have at the moment.

However, there is [a discussion on the Roslyn repository on GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/119) about bringing language-level support for code contracts in C#. The issue has been deemed as being of *some* interest (though not *strong* interest) for inclusion in [the feature set of C# 7](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/2136).

Regarding the subject of LSP, there hasn't been any mention of it in that particular discussion. For example, there is no mention of the possibility of strengthening postconditions and weakening preconditions when specializing a virtual method.

Comment: Language level support is what I want. I'm satisfied using Code Contracts until then, however.